# What is the performance and the performance per watt of Raspberry Pi 3 in GFLOPS

Tags: performance

What is the performance of Raspberry Pi 3 in GFLOPS if the CPU is running at 100% and that the GPU is not running at all?

Comment: Less than 1 ;)  May be interesting: http://hackaday.com/2012/09/12/64-rasberry-pis-turned-into-a-supercomputer/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actual measurements from a few minutes ago as of writing:

- 1st run: 2.817 GFlops
- 2nd run: 2.754 GFlops
- 3rd run: 2.683 GFlops

No overclock, Raspbain Lite. I'll be re-compiling LINPACK and I'll update this answer in a few hours.

Binary used below came from http://web.eece.maine.edu/~vweaver/junk/pi3_hpl.tar.gz

---

My Pi's output:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mv HPL.dat linpack/
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mv xhpl linpack/
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd linpack/
pi@raspberrypi:~/linpack $ ls
HPL.dat  xhpl
pi@raspberrypi:~/linpack $ ./xhpl
================================================================================
HPLinpack 2.1  --  High-Performance Linpack benchmark  --   October 26, 2012
Written by A. Petitet and R. Clint Whaley,  Innovative Computing Laboratory, UTK
Modified by Piotr Luszczek, Innovative Computing Laboratory, UTK
Modified by Julien Langou, University of Colorado Denver
================================================================================

An explanation of the input/output parameters follows:
T/V    : Wall time / encoded variant.
N      : The order of the coefficient matrix A.
NB     : The partitioning blocking factor.
P      : The number of process rows.
Q      : The number of process columns.
Time   : Time in seconds to solve the linear system.
Gflops : Rate of execution for solving the linear system.

The following parameter values will be used:

N      :    8000
NB     :     256
PMAP   : Row-major process mapping
P      :       1
Q      :       1
PFACT  :    Left
NBMIN  :       2
NDIV   :       2
RFACT  :   Right
BCAST  :   2ring
DEPTH  :       0
SWAP   : Mix (threshold = 64)
L1     : transposed form
U      : transposed form
EQUIL  : yes
ALIGN  : 8 double precision words

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

- The matrix A is randomly generated for each test.
- The following scaled residual check will be computed:
      ||Ax-b||_oo / ( eps * ( || x ||_oo * || A ||_oo + || b ||_oo ) * N )
- The relative machine precision (eps) is taken to be               1.110223e-16
- Computational tests pass if scaled residuals are less than                16.0

================================================================================
T/V                N    NB     P     Q               Time                 Gflops
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WR02R2L2        8000   256     1     1             121.22              2.817e+00
HPL_pdgesv() start time Sat Jul  9 01:26:12 2016

HPL_pdgesv() end time   Sat Jul  9 01:28:14 2016

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
||Ax-b||_oo/(eps*(||A||_oo*||x||_oo+||b||_oo)*N)=        0.0025941 ...... PASSED
================================================================================

Finished      1 tests with the following results:
              1 tests completed and passed residual checks,
              0 tests completed and failed residual checks,
              0 tests skipped because of illegal input values.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

End of Tests.
================================================================================
pi@raspberrypi:~/linpack $ ./xhpl
================================================================================
HPLinpack 2.1  --  High-Performance Linpack benchmark  --   October 26, 2012
Written by A. Petitet and R. Clint Whaley,  Innovative Computing Laboratory, UTK
Modified by Piotr Luszczek, Innovative Computing Laboratory, UTK
Modified by Julien Langou, University of Colorado Denver
================================================================================

An explanation of the input/output parameters follows:
T/V    : Wall time / encoded variant.
N      : The order of the coefficient matrix A.
NB     : The partitioning blocking factor.
P      : The number of process rows.
Q      : The number of process columns.
Time   : Time in seconds to solve the linear system.
Gflops : Rate of execution for solving the linear system.

The following parameter values will be used:

N      :    8000
NB     :     256
PMAP   : Row-major process mapping
P      :       1
Q      :       1
PFACT  :    Left
NBMIN  :       2
NDIV   :       2
RFACT  :   Right
BCAST  :   2ring
DEPTH  :       0
SWAP   : Mix (threshold = 64)
L1     : transposed form
U      : transposed form
EQUIL  : yes
ALIGN  : 8 double precision words

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

- The matrix A is randomly generated for each test.
- The following scaled residual check will be computed:
      ||Ax-b||_oo / ( eps * ( || x ||_oo * || A ||_oo + || b ||_oo ) * N )
- The relative machine precision (eps) is taken to be               1.110223e-16
- Computational tests pass if scaled residuals are less than                16.0

================================================================================
T/V                N    NB     P     Q               Time                 Gflops
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WR02R2L2        8000   256     1     1             123.97              2.754e+00
HPL_pdgesv() start time Sat Jul  9 01:30:11 2016

HPL_pdgesv() end time   Sat Jul  9 01:32:15 2016

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
||Ax-b||_oo/(eps*(||A||_oo*||x||_oo+||b||_oo)*N)=        0.0025941 ...... PASSED
================================================================================

Finished      1 tests with the following results:
              1 tests completed and passed residual checks,
              0 tests completed and failed residual checks,
              0 tests skipped because of illegal input values.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

End of Tests.
================================================================================
pi@raspberrypi:~/linpack $ ./xhpl
================================================================================
HPLinpack 2.1  --  High-Performance Linpack benchmark  --   October 26, 2012
Written by A. Petitet and R. Clint Whaley,  Innovative Computing Laboratory, UTK
Modified by Piotr Luszczek, Innovative Computing Laboratory, UTK
Modified by Julien Langou, University of Colorado Denver
================================================================================

An explanation of the input/output parameters follows:
T/V    : Wall time / encoded variant.
N      : The order of the coefficient matrix A.
NB     : The partitioning blocking factor.
P      : The number of process rows.
Q      : The number of process columns.
Time   : Time in seconds to solve the linear system.
Gflops : Rate of execution for solving the linear system.

The following parameter values will be used:

N      :    8000
NB     :     256
PMAP   : Row-major process mapping
P      :       1
Q      :       1
PFACT  :    Left
NBMIN  :       2
NDIV   :       2
RFACT  :   Right
BCAST  :   2ring
DEPTH  :       0
SWAP   : Mix (threshold = 64)
L1     : transposed form
U      : transposed form
EQUIL  : yes
ALIGN  : 8 double precision words

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

- The matrix A is randomly generated for each test.
- The following scaled residual check will be computed:
      ||Ax-b||_oo / ( eps * ( || x ||_oo * || A ||_oo + || b ||_oo ) * N )
- The relative machine precision (eps) is taken to be               1.110223e-16
- Computational tests pass if scaled residuals are less than                16.0

================================================================================
T/V                N    NB     P     Q               Time                 Gflops
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WR02R2L2        8000   256     1     1             127.25              2.683e+00
HPL_pdgesv() start time Sat Jul  9 01:33:39 2016

HPL_pdgesv() end time   Sat Jul  9 01:35:46 2016

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
||Ax-b||_oo/(eps*(||A||_oo*||x||_oo+||b||_oo)*N)=        0.0025941 ...... PASSED
================================================================================

Finished      1 tests with the following results:
              1 tests completed and passed residual checks,
              0 tests completed and failed residual checks,
              0 tests skipped because of illegal input values.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

End of Tests.
================================================================================
pi@raspberrypi:~/linpack $ cat /boot/config.txt
# For more options and information see
# http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
#disable_overscan=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=1

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable the lirc-rpi module
#dtoverlay=lirc-rpi

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on
start_x=0
gpu_mem=64
pi@raspberrypi:~/linpack $
```

Comment: Something is really off with this. I'll do more tests.

Comment: While OP did ask for GFLOPS, they did ask for performance per watt, not raw performance.

Answer (score -1):

From your data:

```
===================================================================
T/V             N    NB     P     Q          Time            Gflops
-------------------------------------------------------------------
WR02R2L2     8000   256     1     1        121.22         2.817e+00
```

Compared to the super computers at [RIKEN and Oak Ridge](https://www.top500.org/green500/lists/2019/06/), which at 14.7 Gflops/watt are 5 times more efficient, the Pi 3 is not too shabby, considering you actually have access to the Pi.

Comment: I do not understand what you try to explain. What are these numbers and letters?

Comment: @Ingo Thank you. I changed the answer to just a straight comparison to the top two supercomputers.